# How do I error handle a REST API call with no results?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, http-headers

I have a PowerQuery function o retrieve the contents of a SharePoint list.

```
let
    Source = (url as any) => 
    let
        aSource = OData.Feed(url, null, [Implementation="2.0"]),
    in
        #"aSource"
in
    Source
```

But sometimes the list doesn't exist, and OData REST API calls don't seem to have a nice set of HTTP type response codes. The code bombs out with a msg

```
OData version 3 and 4 Error The server returned an error: (404) Not found. (List 'ABC' does not exist at site ......)
```

But if I paste the URL into a browser, I get a XML response, with no HTTP error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best answer, because I am not good at PowerQueries.

Perhaps, you can first filter the lists by title:

```
/_api/Web/Lists/?$filter=Title eq 'My List Name'
```

This way, if the returned array of lists contains 0 items, then your list does not exist.

If the filtered list returned 1 item - you are good to proceed to retrieve list items.

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I do. but the problem is that the returned item is a "table" datatype... or the error above